# How do I create notifications for comment replies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a type of threaded comment system on my app. I'm using https://github.com/rails-engine/notifications/ to notify whenever a comment is created. How do I create notifications also for the comment replies?

This is what I did for single comment notification

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', optional: true
has_many :replies, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

  after_commit :notify_comment_created, on: [:create]
  def notify_comment_created
    return if self.commentable.blank?
    receiver_id = self.commentable&.user_id

    Notification.create(
      notify_type: "comment",
      target: self,
      second_target: self.commentable,
      actor_id: self.user_id,
      user_id: receiver_id
    )
  end
```

notifications/comment.html.erb

```
<% if notification.second_target.is_a?(Article) %>
    <div class=''>
      <p class="notifications-p"><i class="fa fa-comment text-secondary"></i> <b><%= link_to notification.actor.username, main_app.profile_path(notification.actor.username) %></b> commented on your <b><%= notification.second_target.class.name %>:</b> <b><%= link_to notification.second_target.title, main_app.article_path(notification.second_target) %></b></p>
    </div>

    <div class=''>
      <p class="notifications-p"><i><%= truncate(notification.target.content, length: 100) %></i></p>
    </div>
  <% elsif notification.second_target.is_a?(Announcement) %>
    <div class=''>
      <p class="notifications-p"><i class="fa fa-comment text-secondary"></i> <b><%= link_to notification.actor.username, main_app.profile_path(notification.actor.username) %></b> commented on your <b><%= notification.second_target.class.name %>:</b> <b><%= link_to notification.second_target.title, main_app.announcement_path(notification.second_target) %></b></p>
    </div>

    <div class=''>
      <p class="notifications-p"><i><%= truncate(notification.target.content, length: 100) %></i></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

comment_table in schema

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "commentable_type"
    t.bigint "commentable_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "parent_id"
    t.index ["commentable_type", "commentable_id"], name: "index_comments_on_commentable_type_and_commentable_id"
    t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_comments_on_parent_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
end
```

_comment.html.erb

```
...
<li id="comment_<%= comment.id %>" class="comment">
   <%= link_to "Reply", polymorphic_path([:reply, comment.commentable, comment]), class: 'reply-comment-link', remote: true  %>
  <% if comment.replies.any? %>
    <ul>
      <%= render comment.replies %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

reply.js.erb

```
<% if @comment.errors.empty? %>
  $("#comment_<%= @comment.id %> > .comment-info .reply-comment-link").removeAttr("href");
  $("#comment_<%= @comment.id %> > .comment-info").after("<%=j render('comments/form', comment: @reply) %>");
...
<% end %>
```

Currently if a comment is replied, the self.commentable gets the notification of the reply as a new comment. What I want in summary is that I want the comment.user get the notification as reply.

**UPDATE:**

I did as suggested below, I added a if (notification.target.parent.present?) {.....text as reply....} else {...your current code...} on the notification view?

Now the thing I need to do next is to changer the reciever_id depending on if notification.target.parent is present on the notification page. If it is, I would love to leave it as it is in my comment model else, I would change the reciever_id to the comment.parent.user... Any way I can do that???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the actual question, but couldn't you just add an `if (notification.target.parent.present?) {.....text as reply....} else {...your current code...}` on the notification view?

Comment: Ah, that's great. Never thought of that but is there a way to notify the the owner of the comment that was replied to instead of the owner of the post/article according to the notifications setup on my comment model... Probably with some ifelse statement? Thanks!